# how to sort two columns dependently based on one column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like

```
V1  V2 V3     V4  V5
a   bc  bm1   a   hdg7
ab  dd  dt3   bc  09Y
ac  ab  gh22  dd  JKJ8
dd  a   hd7   ac  hn
bc            ab  ml
```

I want to sort V2 and V3 based ob V1 (V3 is dependent to V2)

output is like below

```
V1  V2 V3    V4   V5 
a   a   hd7   a   hdg7 
ab  ab  gh22  ab  ml
ac  -   -     ac  hn
dd  dd  dt3   dd  JKJ8
bc  bc  bm1   bc  09Y
```

In fact, I can find the index of those elements of V2 which are similar to V1 but I don't know how them arrange V2, V3 based on that

```
matches <- unique(c(which(outer(df$V1, df$V2, "=="), arr.ind=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match`

```
indx23 <- with(df1, match(V1, V2))
indx45 <- with(df1, match(V1, V4))
df1[2:3] <- df1[indx23,2:3]
df1[4:5] <- df1[indx45,4:5]
 df1[is.na(df1)] <-''
df1
#  V1 V2   V3 V4   V5
#1  a  a  hd7  a hdg7
#2 ab ab gh22 ab   ml
#3 ac         ac   hn
#4 dd dd  dt3 dd JKJ8
#5 bc bc  bm1 bc  09Y
```

If there are more columns, you could use a `loop` with `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
j1 <- as.integer(seq(2, ncol(df1), by=2)) 
setDT(df1)
for(j in j1){
  indx <- match(df1[['V1']], df1[[j]])
  set(df1, i=NULL, j=j, value=df1[[j]][indx])
  set(df1, i=NULL, j=j+1L, value=df1[[j+1L]][indx])
 }
df1
#   V1 V2   V3 V4   V5
#1:  a  a  hd7  a hdg7
#2: ab ab gh22 ab   ml
#3: ac NA   NA ac   hn
#4: dd dd  dt3 dd JKJ8
#5: bc bc  bm1 bc  09Y
```

Or using `Map` from `base R`

```
df1[-1] <- setNames(do.call(`cbind`,
           Map(function(x,y,z) data.frame(y,z)[match(x,y),], 
                df1['V1'], df1[j1], df1[j1+1])), names(df1)[-1])
df1[is.na(df1)] <- ''
df1
#  V1 V2   V3 V4   V5
#1  a  a  hd7  a hdg7
#2 ab ab gh22 ab   ml
#3 ac         ac   hn
#4 dd dd  dt3 dd JKJ8
#5 bc bc  bm1 bc  09Y
```

Comment: @Nemo You got a lot of solutions for that post.  Do you think that doesn't answer the question posted there?

Comment: @Nemo I think the examples here and in that post may be different.  I didn't read the other post carefully, but there are `data.table` solutions as well which would be fast

Comment: OK I will accept the answer for that question, can you please revise your answer when there is column 4 and 5 or even more columns exist ? because with your solution when I have more columns it messes up

Comment: @Nemo Updated the solution.  If there are more columns, we can loop it though..  It depends upon the columns you want to match.  Here, you are matching `V1`, with `V2` `V4`

Comment: you know I always learn from you !!!! I really appreciate all your comments/solutions on my post, THANKS

Comment: @Nemo No problem.  Glad to help you again.